# Problem with connecting to postgresql in azure data studio

Tags: postgresql, azure, localhost, postgresql-16

so today I was trying to install postgresql database and I decided to not use pgAmin4 so I didn't even install it. instead I want to use azure data studio for the DB interface. I think the first step is to create a connection to the postgres. by which I installed the extension first and tried to create a postgresql connection. filled the server name with LocalHost and I don't know what Should I put in the username and password field. I don't know the default values, and I didn't change it at all. (never installed any database on this windows before)
the only unusual thing is that I changed the data folder directory to another drive.

I've tried using admin and postgres as username but each time an error occurs saying the password or username is not valid(or something like that)

Comment: There usual way of installing on windows (The EDB-supplied community installer) doesn't have a default password, but rather prompts for one to be entered upon installation.  If you installed some other way, you need to tell us what that was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Postgres database does not have a default password. It is generated during the installation of Postgres SQL on a Windows machine, and the user is also specified at that time, as shown below:

[image]

You can use these as the username and password when connecting to the Postgres database in Azure Data Studio:

[image]

The connection will be successful, as shown below:

[image]

If you use pgAdmin, you can change the password for the user, as shown below:

[image]

Comment: I am very glad it helped you!